# odd/even number program doesn't print anything

Tags: java, loops, logic

When I run this nothing prints, I am trying to print a message saying odd or even depending on what the user types.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Questions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Your number");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i > 0; i = +2) {
            if (number == i) {
                System.out.println("even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("odd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i > 0`, so you'll get one loop, or chance and the user input better be `0` otherwise it won't match

Comment: your for stop condition (i> 0) and start condition (i=0) are incoherents. if i = 0, i could not be strictly positive. Hence, your for stop condition should be "i>=0"

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Actually, because `i = 0`, the loop is never executed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is never entered, because you initialize `i` with `0` and your first test is `i > 0` (and you don't want a [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Unary_operation#Unary_negative_and_positive) 2, `= +2`). I would also use formatted IO. Putting that together, I think you wanted something like

```
int number = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%d even%n", i);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("%d odd%n", i);
    }
}
```

If you're trying to avoid modulo (and use addition by 2) you could optimize with something like

```
int number = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < number; i += 2) {
    System.out.printf("%d even%n", i);
    System.out.printf("%d odd%n", i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Questions {
public static void main (String[]args) {

Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Your number");
int number = input.nextInt();
if(number % 2 == 0)
     System.out.println("even");
}else {
System.out.println("odd");
}
}
```

Comment: The question remains "why"? (Yes I know, but you need to sell that idea to the OP)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, OP's logic seems dont get the Even or Odd number.

Comment: I'm aware of what the OP did wrong and have plenty ideas of my own about they might solve it, but why should the OP choose your solution over any other?  The question isn't so much about how to determine if the value is odd or even, but why the loop wouldn't run ;)

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to try this way...

```
        if ((number % 2) ==0) {
            System.out.println("even");
        } else {
            System.out.println("odd");
        }
```

As you initialize `i` and the condition seems to be `i>0` so it will always be false so for loop never executed

As @MadProgrammer stated in comments your loop never executed.

> because i = 0, the loop is never executed ;)

Comment: The question remains "why"? (Yes I know, but you need to sell that idea to the OP)